# Ionic 3 - How to Merge Array of Objects with valueChanges Observable

Tags: javascript, firebase-realtime-database, ionic3, angularfire2

I have two arrays of objects to merge them. The first one is the result from a snapshotChanges retrieve (participants), and the second one is the result from a valueChanges retrieve (usersRoom).

```
//First one (participants)
participants = [
  {id: 123, message: 'OK'},
  {id: 456, message: 'Hey'}
];

//Second one (usersRoom)
for(var i=0; i < this.participants.length; i++){
  this.room = this.db.object('users/' + this.participants[i].id).valueChanges();
  this.room.subscribe(
     res => {
        this.usersRoom.push(res);
     });
}
```

But when I try to merge them, using the code below, this returns an empty array:

```
this.final = this.usersRoom.reduce((arr, e) => {
      arr.push(Object.assign({}, e, this.participants.find(a => a.id === e.id)))
      return arr;
}, [])
```

I checked if I created a fake object instead of grabbing the valueChanges, only to validate the code that runs the merge above, and works perfectly.

When I run console.log in the results, I noticed that they appear in different ways on the console (see the first line for each one):

```
//participants
(2) [{…}, {…}]
 0: {id: "123", message: "OK"}
 1: {id: "456", message: "Hey"}
//usersRoom
[]
 0: {name: "John", age: "28", id: "123"}
 1: {name: "Mary", age: "32", id: "456"}
```

It seems to me that both are not the same format, so they end up not being merged.
So how can I do it so they can be merged?

Answer (score 0):

if I understand correctly you are trying to get this

```
merge(){
    let ids = [];
    let merge_obj = [];

    let participants = [
      {id: 123, message: 'OK'},
      {id: 456, message: 'Hey'}
    ];

    let usersRoom = [
      {name: "John", age: "28", id: "123"},
      {name: "Mary", age: "32", id: "456"}
    ];

    participants.map( (obj) => {
      let index = ids.indexOf(obj.id);
      if( !( index > -1 ) )
      {
        ids.push(obj.id.toString());
      }
    });

    usersRoom.map( (obj) => {
      let index = ids.indexOf(obj.id);
      if( !(index > -1 ) )
      {
        merge_obj.push(obj);
      }
      else
      {
        let keys : Array<string> = Object.keys( obj );
        let objMerge = participants.filter( o => {
          if( o.id.toString() == obj.id )
          {
              let keysMerge : Array<string> = Object.keys( o );
              keysMerge.forEach( value => {
                if ( keys.indexOf(value) == -1 ) {
                  obj[value]=o[value];
                }
              });
          }
          return obj;
        })
        merge_obj.push(obj);
      }
    });
    console.log(merge_obj);
  }
```

merge_obj

```
0: {name: "John", age: "28", id: "123", message: "OK"}
1: {name: "Mary", age: "32", id: "456", message: "Hey"}
```

Comment: Yes, the final result should be as your merge_obj object. But, as I mentioned before, if I had created both arrays manually (as you did), my previous code has worked as well. The problem is that, in fact, the usersRoom array is the result from valueChanges observable, and therefore I can't merge both arrays.